# What's the diffence between has or have when we have 2 things?

Tags: grammar, verbs

I found this question and I get a little confused with the use of has and have when there is more than two things together.

**Do you agree or disagree with the following statement?

Modern transportation and shipping has made the world a better place to live.**

I know how to use has and have in the simple form, but I would like to know how big is the difference between has and have in the high level. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question the writer must decide is "are there two things, or one thing (in two parts).

If I have two things I use "have"

> Plastic and paper have made the world a better place.

But here the writer has decided (correctly) that "transport and shipping" is conceptually one thing. So they use "has". There is scope here for judgement and you can be flexible.